# NSValue to CLLocationCoordinate2D in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, nsvalue, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am using `Contentful.com` as a content-backend for my `iOS` app. I can not get their `geo-point` return to work for me in my `Swift` project.

The Contentful documentation says their `API` returns "`NSData` with `CLLocationCoordinate2D struct`."

I am approaching this with `NSValue` in my project, but I can not get it to work properly. Here's my code:

```
var locationCoord:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0,longitude: 0)

var locationData:NSData = entry.fields["location"] as NSData

var locationValue:NSValue = NSValue(bytes: locationData.bytes, objCType: "CLLocationCoordinate2D")

locationCoord = locationValue.MKCoordinateValue
```

However, `locationCoord.latitude` and `locationCoord.longitude` `return` wrong values (one of them always being `0.0`).

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here, and how to make this work properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, `getBytes:length:` from `NSData` would be sufficient:

```
var locationData = entry.fields["location"] as NSData
var locationCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
locationData.getBytes(&locationCoord, length: sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D))
```

---

BTW, Why your code doen't work?

That is: `objCType:` parameter is not expecting a type name "String", but expecting ["Type Encodings"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html), in this case that is `{?=dd}`. In Objective-C, you have handy `@encode(TypeName)`, but not in Swift. The easiest way to get that is to use `.objCType` property of `NSValue`.

```
var locationData = entry.fields["location"] as NSData
var locationCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
var objCType = NSValue(MKCoordinate: locationCoord).objCType // <- THIS IS IT
var locationValue = NSValue(bytes: locationData.bytes, objCType: objCType)
locationCoord = locationValue.MKCoordinateValue
```

---

Moreover, It seems `CDAEntry` in Contentful SDK has [the exact API](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.objc/blob/dd2ca4373d08dbe2b4d41c7b1690f1bafd285222/Code/CDAEntry.h#L33), I think you should use this:

```
/**
 Retrieve the value of a specific Field as a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` for easy interaction with
 CoreLocation or MapKit.

 @param identifier  The `sys.id` of the Field which should be queried.
 @return The actual location value of the Field.
 @exception NSIllegalArgumentException If the specified Field is not of type Location.
 */
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)CLLocationCoordinate2DFromFieldWithIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier;
```

Comment: FYI when using the code to get the objCType for CLLocationCoordinate2D, don't forget to `import MapKit`